# Database name in Wordpress / PDO error reporting

Tags: php, wordpress, pdo

I apologize in advance if this turns out to be a stupid question, but I've been racking my brain for an hour already.

I normally work in PHP with Laravel, but now I've been plunged into a project that uses a Wordpress database and a custom framework which uses PDO queries directly from the controller (no models exist); I need help figuring something out since I'm very inexperienced in Wordpress and PDO.

The client gave me a link to a database named `simb2317419733`, it has a Wordpress structure and the prefix is `wp_wd5t1y9832_`.

However, the queries on the site seem to reference tables that don't exist in this database. For example, the following query is trying to insert into a table named `answers` but:

1) no such table exists in the database
2) no error is thrown

Here is the query info:

http://pastebin.com/n08LnFbK

Notice that all the info matches the database above (host, user, password, prefix) but the database name itself is just `wordpress`. Is this a normal occurrence in Wordpress, or is this a case of the client simply giving me the wrong database which happens to have the same prefix? Or is the `answers` table missing but PDO isn't reporting the error for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Check that plugin how it creates the connection to database. There are two options: or it connects to the same database like the whole worpdress using constants from wp_config file, or there is plugin configuration, where you can provide different connection details. It can be either set in wp admin panel or some config files... But if you figure out, that it is using the same database, then there are two options. As you said, you've received wrong information. The second: plugin is not installed and it hasn't set up its tables.

Comment: It doesn't seem to use the settings from the `wp-config` file. I tried changing the database name and user to random values just now, and nothing changed. I tried searching the database name `simb2317419733` in all the site files and it doesn't appear anywhere, and I don't have access to any sort of WP admin panel. The client isn't technically very literate and their previous dev abandoned them, so I'm not sure how to present this problem to them.

Comment: http://domain/wp-admin/  <- there is your wp admin panel. You need to ask for an admin account and password. /wp-config.php <- here you should find db info used by WP itself. And source of your plugin should be in /wp-content/plugins/{plugin-name}/ . Maybe that will help you to get some orientation where you should be looking for what...

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing - is there any way I can know which plugin to look into? There's over 20 in that directory.

Comment: Search for occurrences of `answers` table in files located in plugins directory? `grep -R answers *`?